# react-native how to change usestate data getting from other page?

Tags: javascript, react-native

i'm beginner of react-native. help me haha...

i give a useState data ('playlist') from MainPage.js to playList.js

in MainPage.js

```
const [playList, setPlayList] = useState([]);

<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigate('PlayList', {data: playList})}>
```

in playList.js

```
const Imagetake = ({url}) => {
url =url.replace('{w}', '100');
url = url.replace('{h}', '100');
return <Image style ={{height:'100%', width:'100%'}} source ={{url:url}}/>
};
const PlayList = ({ navigation }) => {
    const playList = navigation.getParam('data');
    const setPlayList = navigation.getParam('setData');
    const deletePlayList = (data) => {
        setPlayList(playList.filter((song)=> song.id != data.id));
    };
    return (
        <View style={styles.posts}>
            <FlatList
                data={playList}
                keyExtractor={posts => posts.id}
                renderItem={({item}) =>{
                    return (
                        <View>
                            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => deletePlayList( item )}>
                                <Ionicons name="trash-outline" size={30}/>
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                            <TouchableOpacity>
                                <View style={styles.post}>
                                    <View style ={styles.postcontent}>
                                        <Imagetake url={item.attributes.artwork.url}></Imagetake>
                                    </View>
                                    <View style={styles.posthead}>
                                        <View style = {styles.postheadtext}>
                                            <Text style ={styles.posttitletext}>{item.attributes.name}</Text>
                                            <Text style={styles.username}>{item.attributes.artistName}</Text>
                                        </View>
                                        <View style = {styles.postheadtext2}>
                                            <Text style={styles.username}>{item.attributes.albumName}</Text>
                                        </View>
                                    </View>
                                </View>
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                        </View>
                    )
                }}
            />
        </View>
    );
};
```

when i delete some songs in playList, it is well done in playList page. but when i go to mainpage and go to playList again, delete is useless. the songs that i deleted before is refreshed. how can i fix it? T^T

Answer (score 0):

You may also pass the `setPlayList` function to `PlayList` page.

And instead of creating another `useState` in the child page, you directly call the `setPlayList` that is passed from parent page

Comment: i do that when u states, so when i go back to playList again, it is deleted well.
but, when i delete songs, in that page i still see deleted songs..

Comment: That's probably because react native didn't detect your change of state. Could you provide more information by such as posting the part that renders your page?

Comment: i change contents, in playList.js Thanks a lot.